# C# Pointers and Properties

Tags: c#, winforms, get, set

I'm making a windows forms application and I'm trying to improve my code so I'd like a little bit of advice/help.

I have a list with data at lets say my first form that I add data to from a database. I then pass around one persons details from that list rather than the whole list. My Problem is that I don't think I'm passing around data correctly and I'd like to do it correctly.

Example of what I'm doing (accountholders is of type object?):
Form 2 =I want to pass the data into this form:

```
private AccountHolders person;

public void SetThePersonsValue(AccountHolders inputAccountHolder)
{
    person = inputAccountHolder;
}
```

Form 1 = I'm taking data from this form, I want to update the list that in this form later on:

```
WithdrawNoReceipt withdrawNoReceipt = new WithdrawNoReceipt();
withdrawNoReceipt.SetThePersonsValue(person);
withdrawNoReceipt.ShowDialog();
```

So I want to use a get/set property (?) to do this but I'm not sure how to do so.. Ideally I want the person I'm passing around to be a pointer so the originally list gets updated so I can write the data back to the database without passing the data back to the first form.

If you need any more information please let me know! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a property? because then you need to add the following code

```
private AccountHolders person;

public AccountHolders Person
{
 get{return person;}
 set{person = value;}
}
```

the property points to the private member person. Ideally you add a PropertyChanged event in the property so your form knows something has been updated?

EDIT:

For filling the property value, value is of type AccountHolders

```
public void SetThePersonsValue(AccountHolders inputAccountHolder)
{
    //Set the value
    Person = inputAccountHolder;
}

WithdrawNoReceipt withdrawNoReceipt = new WithdrawNoReceipt();
//get the value
WithdrawNoReceipt.SetThePersonsValue(Person);
WithdrawNoReceipt.ShowDialog();
```

while debugging you will now see you person object changes whenever you update your Person object

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would I pass the value into the property?